# Android - Search ListView content using custom BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, baseadapter

I am having a ListView and I have inserted values using BaseAdapter.
this is a my BaseAdapter's source code

```
private class BankNameAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context activity;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Bank bank;
    private List<Bank> data;
    private List<Bank> orig;
    UserHolder holder = null;

    public BankNameAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Bank> data) {

        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.activity = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
            holder = new UserHolder();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder.PersonType = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_tittle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        bank = data.get(position);


        holder.PersonType.setText(bank.getBank());



        return row;

    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<Bank> results = new ArrayList<>();
                if (orig == null)
                    orig = data;
                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                        for (final Bank uBanks : orig) {
                            if (uBanks.getBank().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString()))
                                results.add(uBanks);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                data = (ArrayList<Bank>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    class UserHolder {
        public TextView PersonType;

    }

}
```

in Edittext's addTextChangedListener method i try to search values by names.search working perfect but when i clicked items,from item selected,selected always first iteam
for example i have ['one',two',three'four'] elements in arraylist and if i search 'four'(in listview i can show only 'four') but when i click selected item
resutl is 'one' always first elements in my arraylist
i have no idea what is a wrong in my code

```
private void ShowDialogWithHeader(String header) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_show_register_dialog);
    popapListview = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.registerPopapList);
    final EditText searchCountry = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Search_Country);
    final TextView headerTxt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.register_popap_header_txt);

    if (cashBanks != null) {
        bankList = Arrays.asList(cashBanks);
        bankNameAdapter = new BankNameAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_category_adapter, bankList);
        popapListview.setAdapter(bankNameAdapter);
    }


    headerTxt.setText(header);


    popapListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            Bank bank = bankList.get(position);
            mSelectedBank = bank;

            mBank.setText(bank.getBank());
            mBankCode.setText(bank.getBankcode());
            dialog.dismiss();


        }


    });
    searchCountry.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            System.out.println("Text [" + s + "]");

            bankNameAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });



    dialog.show();
}
```

this is a my code 
if anyone knows solutions please add me thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

this is a problem

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}
```

correct answer is

```
 @Override
 public Bank getItem(int position) {
 return data.get(position);
    }

Bank bank = bankNameAdapter.getItem(position);
```

working perfect. i solved myself

Answer (score 0):

in your on itemclick replace your

```
Bank bank = bankList.get(position);
```

with

```
 Bank bank = (Bank)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```